# docker-compose entrypoint commands get stuck

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, docker, execute-command

I'm trying to add "curl" to a container permanently so it can do health checks like this:

```
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl --fail -s -I https://localhost:port || exit 1"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 5s
```

When I ssh into the container and run these 2 commands, curl is installed:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install curl -y
```

Pretty simple, right?
So when I try to add these commands to an entrypoint in my docker-compose like this:

```
entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "-c" , "apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y"]
```

The curl install gets stuck at:

> Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...

Now when I remove "apt-get install curl -y" the "apt-get update" command gets stuck as well, here:

> Fetched 22.8 MB in 2s (12.8 MB/s) Reading package lists...

When I SSH into the container and try my commands, nothing gets stuck.
I tried to do this on a completely different container and get the same result, so I'm doing something wrong.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you need to add the curl install to the container Dockerfile and rebuild the container.

Comment: When doing that I would need to create a dockerfile everytime the container has an update.
Or is there an automated workflow for that?